# get gps location with android - not always working

Tags: android, gps

I'm working on an android app, the idea is that the user logs and sends a form to a database. This form also contains the actual position of the user using gps.

This is the code I'm using:

Oncreate ->

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, locationListener);
```

Then the class ->

```
class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            long variance;
            variance = age_minutes(loc);


            if (variance < 1) {

                Log.v("asdf","we are inside" + variance);

                posH.longitude = String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude());
                Log.v("asdf", posH.longitude);
                posH.latitude = String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude());
                Log.v("asdf", posH.latitude);

                posH.valid = true;

            } else {

                Log.v("asdf","we are outside" + variance);
                posH.valid = false;
            }


        }
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't always work:
For example, I open the form, I press send but onlocationchanged is not called until I wait 20 seconds, sometimes more, sometimes is never called, doesn't matter if I move or not.

I want a method that let me open the form, and automatically get the current gps position...

Answer (score 1):

You can use start with last know location until you get more current data.

```
Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

From [Android Location Strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html):

Obtaining user location from a mobile device can be complicated. There are several reasons why a location reading (regardless of the source) can contain errors and be inaccurate. Some sources of error in the user location include:

- Multitude of location sources
  GPS, Cell-ID, and Wi-Fi can each provide a clue to users location. Determining which to use and trust is a matter of trade-offs in accuracy, speed, and battery-efficiency.
- User movement
  Because the user location changes, you must account for movement by re-estimating user location every so often.
- Varying accuracy
  Location estimates coming from each location source are not consistent in their accuracy. A location obtained 10 seconds ago from one source might be more accurate than the newest location from another or same source.
  These problems can make it difficult to obtain a reliable user location reading.

Comment: Sometimes lastknownlocation is empty, this results in getting absolutely no location.

Comment: Use lastKnownLocation as starting point, and then use your existing code to listen and get better location data. Anyway, there is no guarantee that you will be able to get correct or any location data. You just have to adjust your app to deal with it.